# Select only records with distinct values in a certain row

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, distinct, ms-access-2010

I have following sample data:

```
ID    Name    Street    Number    Code
100   John    Street1   1         1234
130   Peter   Street1   2         1234
135   Bob     Street2   1         5678
141   Alice   Street5   3         5678
160   Sara    Street1   3         3456
```

Now I need a Query to return only the last record because its Code is unique.

Comment: Which one should be 'last' record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can identify which codes are unique with a query which uses `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

```sql
SELECT [Code]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [Code]
HAVING Count(*) = 1;
```

To get full rows which match those unique `[Code]` values, join that query back to your table.

```sql
SELECT y.*
FROM
    YourTable AS y
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT [Code]
        FROM YourTable
        GROUP BY [Code]
        HAVING Count(*) = 1
    ) AS sub
ON y.Code = sub.Code;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to HansUp, this is my final query now:

```
SELECT
    A.*
FROM
    (T_NEEDED AS A
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        CODE
    FROM
        T_NEEDED
    GROUP BY
        CODE
    HAVING
        Count(*) = 1
    ) AS B
ON
    A.CODE = B.CODE)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    T_UNNEEDED AS C
ON
    A.ID = C.ID
WHERE
    C.ID Is Null
ORDER BY
    A.NAME,
    A.STREET,
    A.NUMBER
```

Explanation: I have two tables, one with records with IDs that are needed and one with those unneeded. The unneeded IDs might be in the needed table and if they are I want them to be excluded, hence the LEFT OUTER JOIN. Then comes the second part for which opened the question. I want to exclude those records from the needed IDs that have Codes that are not unique or also belong to other IDs.

The result is a table that contains only needed IDs and in this table every Code is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using CTE :

```
WITH tempTbl
          AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY code ORDER BY code ) AS rownm, *
               FROM     yourtable
             )
    SELECT * FROM tempTbl WHERE code NOT IN (SELECT code FROM tempTbl WHERE   rownm > 1)
```